# How can I execute two consecutive PHP scripts declared in one single PHP script?

Tags: php, execute

I have two PHP files.

1) Create.php
2) Insert.php

I would like to create a PHP file that executes the previous PHP scripts
in a row.

e.g.

```
    exec(Create.php);
    exec(Insert.php);
```

Is there any way that I can execute these PHP scripts?
Can I create another PHP script that it can execute the previous scripts?

Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply include them (`require` is the keyword for this):

```
<?php
    require Create.php;
    require Insert.php;

    // depending on what the files contain, you can now execute their
    // functions, instantiate their classes, or in case they produce
    // direct output, it will be visible now.
?>
```

Comment: Btw, concerning different ways to include a file: http://www.paulund.co.uk/difference-between-php-include-and-require

Comment: In Create.php and in Insert.php files, I have already included other php files. So, what is better in my case? include or require?

Comment: In short: Never use `include` or `include_once` – they never made sense. In fact, don't even use `require`, I only used because I didn't know if you need to load these files multiple times. The best would be to wrap your code in functions and classes, then to include them exactly *once*, using `require_once`.